# How to prevent .diff() function to get a ridiculous value when applied to a dataframe of datetimes and NaT values in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have got a dataframe loc_df where all the values are datetime and some of them are NaT. This is what loc_df looks like:

```
loc_df = pd.DataFrame({'10101':['2020-01-03','2019-11-06','2019-10-09','2019-09-26','2019-09-19','2019-08-19','2019-08-08','2019-07-05','2019-07-04','2019-06-27','2019-05-21','2019-04-21','2019-04-15','2019-04-06','2019-03-28','2019-02-28'], '10102':['2020-01-03','2019-11-15','2019-11-11','2019-10-23','2019-10-10','2019-10-06','2019-09-26','2019-07-14','2019-05-21','2019-03-15','2019-03-11','2019-02-27','2019-02-25',None,None,None], '10103':['2019-08-27','2019-07-14','2019-06-24','2019-05-21','2019-04-11','2019-03-06','2019-02-11',None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None,None]})
loc_df = loc_df.apply(pd.to_datetime)

print(loc_df)                                                                                                                                            
        10101      10102      10103
0  2020-01-03 2020-01-03 2019-08-27
1  2019-11-06 2019-11-15 2019-07-14
2  2019-10-09 2019-11-11 2019-06-24
3  2019-09-26 2019-10-23 2019-05-21
4  2019-09-19 2019-10-10 2019-04-11
5  2019-08-19 2019-10-06 2019-03-06
6  2019-08-08 2019-09-26 2019-02-11
7  2019-07-05 2019-07-14        NaT
8  2019-07-04 2019-05-21        NaT
9  2019-06-27 2019-03-15        NaT
10 2019-05-21 2019-03-11        NaT
11 2019-04-21 2019-02-27        NaT
12 2019-04-15 2019-02-25        NaT
13 2019-04-06        NaT        NaT
14 2019-03-28        NaT        NaT
15 2019-02-28        NaT        NaT
```

I want to know the days between the dates for each colum so I have used:

```
loc_df = loc_df.diff(periods = -1)
```

The result was:

```
print(loc_df)                                                                                                                                            
     10101                        10102                        10103
0  58 days             49 days 00:00:00             44 days 00:00:00
1  28 days              4 days 00:00:00             20 days 00:00:00
2  13 days             19 days 00:00:00             34 days 00:00:00
3   7 days             13 days 00:00:00             40 days 00:00:00
4  31 days              4 days 00:00:00             36 days 00:00:00
5  11 days             10 days 00:00:00             23 days 00:00:00
6  34 days             74 days 00:00:00 -88814 days +00:12:43.145224
7   1 days             54 days 00:00:00              0 days 00:00:00
8   7 days             67 days 00:00:00              0 days 00:00:00
9  37 days              4 days 00:00:00              0 days 00:00:00
10 30 days             12 days 00:00:00              0 days 00:00:00
11  6 days              2 days 00:00:00              0 days 00:00:00
12  9 days -88800 days +00:12:43.145224              0 days 00:00:00
13  9 days              0 days 00:00:00              0 days 00:00:00
14 28 days              0 days 00:00:00              0 days 00:00:00
15     NaT                          NaT                          NaT
```

Do you know why I high values at the end of each column? I guess it has something to do with subtract a NaT to a datetime.

Is there an alternative to my code to prevent this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have some initial data:

```
print(loc_df)                                                                                                                                            
        10101      10102      10103
0  2020-01-03 2020-01-03 2019-08-27
1  2019-11-06 2019-11-15 2019-07-14
2  2019-10-09 2019-11-11 2019-06-24
3  2019-09-26 2019-10-23 2019-05-21
4  2019-09-19 2019-10-10 2019-04-11
5  2019-08-19 2019-10-06 2019-03-06
6  2019-08-08 2019-09-26 2019-02-11
7  2019-07-05 2019-07-14        NaT
8  2019-07-04 2019-05-21        NaT
9  2019-06-27 2019-03-15        NaT
10 2019-05-21 2019-03-11        NaT
11 2019-04-21 2019-02-27        NaT
12 2019-04-15 2019-02-25        NaT
13 2019-04-06        NaT        NaT
14 2019-03-28        NaT        NaT
15 2019-02-28        NaT        NaT
```

You could use [`DataFrame.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) to fill in the NaT values before you use `diff()`:

```
loc_df = loc_df.ffill()
loc_df = loc_df.diff(periods=-1)
```

---

```
print(loc_df)                                                                                                                                            
     10101   10102   10103
0  58 days 49 days 44 days
1  28 days  4 days 20 days
2  13 days 19 days 34 days
3   7 days 13 days 40 days
4  31 days  4 days 36 days
5  11 days 10 days 23 days
6  34 days 74 days  0 days
7   1 days 54 days  0 days
8   7 days 67 days  0 days
9  37 days  4 days  0 days
10 30 days 12 days  0 days
11  6 days  2 days  0 days
12  9 days  0 days  0 days
13  9 days  0 days  0 days
14 28 days  0 days  0 days
15     NaT     NaT     NaT
```

Comment: Thank you so mush @dkhara. That is exactly what I was looking for.